# Powershell - Get Unified Group with Mailaddress of the owners

Tags: powershell

I want to send a message to all people who are owners of a public MS Group. So my Code is:

```
Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize unlimited| Where-Object {($_.AccessType -eq "Public")} | Select-Object ManagedBy | Export-csv C:\Path
```

I can get the names, but how can I get the email address of the owners. I want to have it in one list.

Comment: Can't test it, but you probaly have to Pipe the `select-object` to [`Get-MailUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/get-mailuser?view=exchange-ps) and select the Mail from there.

Comment: Like this? `Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize 100 | Where-Object {($_.AccessType -eq "Public")} | Get-MailUser -Identity $_.ManagedBy`

Comment: Seems to be correct (again, can't test it atm). You can then Pipe that to `Export-Csv` if you want to.